# Minecraft command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone please help me fix this command?

> /setblock -10 15 -42 command_block 0 replace {Command:"/testfor @p[r=7] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:magma_cream"}]}"}

Comment: What's wrong with it? Which error are you getting while running it?

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that Minecraft will read the `Command` string as:

```
Command:"/testfor @p[r=7] {Inventory:[{id:"
```

The first `"` starts the string where you want to start it, but then the next `"` ends it early.

To stop quotation marks from ending a string, you can *escape* them by putting a `\` in front, like this:

```
{Command:"/testfor @p[r=7] {Inventory:[{id:\"minecraft:magma_cream\"}]}"}
```

Alternatively, in this situation but not always, you could leave out one or both pairs of quotation marks:

```
{Command:"/testfor @p[r=7] {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:magma_cream}]}"}
{Command:/testfor @p[r=7] {Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:magma_cream"}]}}
{Command:/testfor @p[r=7] {Inventory:[{id:minecraft:magma_cream}]}}
```